# Cookies not set using javascript fetch

Tags: javascript, cookies

If I use `fetch()` in javascript on my page, it doesn't send cookies in the request in Firefox and Edge, In Chrome it works perfectly. Cookies are required for my page due to authentication.

The request is on the same domain, and I don't see any reason why it shouldn't.
I use https.

This doesnt work in Firefox/Edge (No cookies set):

```
    fetch('/kiaweb/notification/key')
    .then(function (res) {
        res.json().then(function (data) {
            self.apiKey = data.key;
        });
    });
```

but this works everywhere (all cookies set) (using jquery):

```
    $.get('/kiaweb/notification/key' function(data) {
    self.apiKey = data.key;});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that I need to set `{ credentials: "same-origin" }`.

The request would be :

```
fetch('/kiaweb/notification/key',{ credentials: "same-origin" })
.then(function (res) {
    res.json().then(function (data) {
        self.apiKey = data.key;
    });
});
```

Comment: This resolved the issue for me as well in Edge 16/17. Note that this is due to a bug in Edge's implementation and has been resolved as of Edge 18.

Answer (score 0):

As per the browser support list, IE does not support `fetch` - 
you can check the support here on [this link](https://caniuse.com/#feat=fetch).

Comment: Sorry, There were one place i wrote IE instead of firefox. IE is not the issue here

Comment: Try checking the version of your firefox. It's supported on v60 and above.